# Can an airplane lift off the ground when lift is equal to weight?

Tags: takeoff

Can a plane lift off the ground at the point when there is the same amount of lift as weight? Or does lift have to be greater?

Comment: see: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/13870

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes they can, in fact aircraft regularly lift off the ground when lift is less than weight. They achieve this by rotating the nose, which provides a vertical component of the thrust vector. See the excellent answers to  [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/12714/why-do-airplanes-lift-up-their-nose-to-climb) for a detailed explanation.